# Invisible Border C#

Tags: c#, winforms, border, collision, mousemove

Okay, so I made a form in C#. You can move the controls around at run-time such as a button, you can move it or a picture. Anyways, I was wondering if there was anyway that you could make some sort of an invisible border, so that you can't drag the controls out of the program's screen. Like in Windows you can drag the window out of the screen area. I don't want you to be able to do that, and I wanted to see if you could also make it to where you could make borders around the control's them self's so that you can't drag them onto of each other. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Well, I'm using DevExpress DXv2 with WinForms.

```
    private void groupControl2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            groupControl2.Left += e.X - move.X;
            groupControl2.Top += e.Y - move.Y;
        }
    }

    private void groupControl2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
             move = e.Location;
        }
```

Comment: How are you implementing this? You shouldn't be able to drag them out of their parent form..

Comment: Don't make the control's Left property less than 0 and more than ClientSize.Width - control.Width.  Etcetera.

Comment: Could you paste some code and screenshots? I'm really curious about it.

Comment: @sneakthief very nice, thanks

Comment: Okay guys, I will make a short YouTube video, about a minute long demonstrating what I am talking about. I really Can't post screenshots in order for you to properly understand it.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9Lxw-koUec&feature=youtu.be

Watch this YouTube video on what I am talking about. It's only about a minute long.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using some sort of Control Assembly that provides you with the panel to drag and drop.

**First check whether that control library has built-in functionality for moving out of the visible window area.**

I suppose it has events indicating that the panel has moved. Check this pseudo code:

```
if (panel.Left < 0) { } // Outside left border
if (panel.Top < 0) { } // Outside top border
if ((panel.Left + panel.Width) > form.Width){ } // Outside right border
if ((panel.Top + panel.Height) > form.Height) { } // Outside bottom border
```

Either:

If the event supports cancel, cancel it in case any of the above is true. Otherwise you could implement something like this pseudo code (Actual WinForms dimensions require a bit different values)

```
// Outside left border
if (panel.Left < 0) { panel.Left = 0; }

// Outside top border
if (panel.Top < 0) { panel.Top = 0; } 

// Outside right border
if ((panel.Left + panel.Width) > form.Width)
{
    panel.Left = form.Width - panel.Width;
} 

// Outside bottom border
if ((panel.Top + panel.Height) > form.Height)
{
    panel.Top = (form.Height - panel.Height);
}
```

Comment: thank you. I will try out this code when I get home and I will report back to you with the results.

Comment: @ClintonLawson Please update your post and include which control library you are using for dragging and dropping functionality.